How did J. J. Thomson conclude that the particles present in cathode rays were not ions but are in fact much smaller than the smallest of all atoms?
What evidence did he have to prove that the particles in cathode rays are much smaller than atoms? Did he have the e/m ratio of hydrogen ion in 1897? If yes, where did he get that from?

This may be better suited for [hsm.se].

Thanks for the comments! I would delete the question after I figured out how to delete it. For some reason that option is not visible to me.

‘Anode’ rays were well known, and the fields required to deflect them were much larger than what was needed to deflect the cathode rays. So, yes, one gets the relative masses from the relative fields.
